# Receiving a strange Xcode error when trying to run app in iOS simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode6

When I try to compile and run my app in the simulator, I receive this error:

[image]

Everything was working fine yesterday.

I tried backing up and deleting `~/Library/Logs`, thinking that might work, but it did not. I'm running Xcode 6.

**EDIT**: I just found out that this problem was caused by me renaming my home folder and shortname. That's fine and well, I undid everything and now my simulator is working. My question still remains, however, how to I get the simulator to stop showing this error? My home folder name and shortname are irrelevant and I'd still like to be able to rename them and have everything work. A user in #iphone-dev on Freenode told me not to do this, in general, because certain apps will complain, but there's a walkthrough on the official Apple support page that says this is copacetic.

Comment: Not sure but few things to try:
1. Make sure there is no file named "~/Library/Logs", and if there it is directory.
2. "~/Library/Logs" have read/write access, and also "~/Library/Logs/iOS Simulator" have read/write access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try any of the following:

- edit all paths in ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/"YOUR_SIMULATOR_GUID"/data/var/run/launchd_bootstrap.plist
- delete and recreate simulator in Xcode (Window -> Devices)
- delete simulator directory from ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices